# Tooling API - Invalid field issue

Tags: apex, lightning, tooling-api

I am using Rest API to update the Apex trigger using ApexTriggerMember.
I am using the below json string as body in request.

```
String json = {"MetadataContainerId" : "1dc7F00000DD9UYQA1", "FullName" : "Suggestion__c" , "Body": "{"Name":"RSLC_Suggestion","Body":"trigger RSLC_Suggestion on Suggestion__c (before insert, before update, after insert, after update){ \n    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert &#124;&#124; trigger.isUpdate &#124;&#124; trigger.isDelete) )\n    { \n      RollUpSummaryGenerator.associationOdChildRecordsToParentRecords(trigger.new,'Suggestion','SuggestionNumber','Contact','SuggestioNumbers'); \n    } \n}","tableEnumOrId":"Suggestion__c"}"}
```

I am receiving the below response

> String response = "[{"message":"No such column 'MetadataContainerId'
>   on sobject of type ApexTrigger","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]"

Can anyone take a look at this issue?

```
public static void createApexTriggerMember(String metadataContainerId, String apexClassId, string classBody)
    {
       // String body = '{"MetadataContainerId" : "'+metadataContainerId+'", "ContentEntityId" : "'+apexClassId+'", "FullName" : "'+'\'Suggestion__c\' , "Body": "'+classBody+'"}';
        String body = '{"MetadataContainerId" : "'+metadataContainerId+'", "FullName" : "'+'Suggestion__c" , "Body": "'+classBody+'"}';
        Http objHTTP = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Tooling_API_Credential/services/data/v44.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexTriggerMember');
        req.setBody(body);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        Http h = new Http();

        String response = h.send(req).getBody();
        System.debug('response= '+response);
        Map<String,Object> rmp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(response);
        String apmid = (String)rmp.get('id');
      //  createContainerAsyncRequest(metadataContainerId);
    }
```

I am getting an additional error as below:

{"message":"Unexpected character ('N' (code 78)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:15]","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}

Is there no one in this salesforce ecosystem who can help me out?

I tried correcting my json. Now I am receiving the below error.

DEBUG|response= [{"message":"No such column 'ContentEntityId ' on sobject of type ApexTriggerMember","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of [ApexTriggerMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apextriggermember.htm)  usage section:

> To edit, save, or compile an Apex trigger, create an ApexTriggerMember
>   object that references it. To create a trigger, use the REST API or
>   the Metadata API.

You cannot create a Trigger using Tooling API. you can only update it.

Creating a trigger using Rest Api is even easier, don't have to create a MetadataContainer or create ApexTriggerMember with complex parameters. Just Insert ApexTrigger with Name, Body and TableEnumOrId and you are sorted:

Sample Post Request :

**Endpoint**: /services/data/v44.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger

```
{"Name" : "MyTrigger" , "Body": "Trigger MyTrigger on Account(after insert){}" ,"TableEnumOrId":"Account"}
```

**Apex Code** :

```
    String body = '{"Name" : "MyTrigger" , "Body": "Trigger MyTrigger on Account(after insert){}" ,"TableEnumOrId":"Account"}';
    Http objHTTP = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:Tooling_API_Credential/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/ApexTrigger');
    req.setBody(body);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    Http h = new Http();

    String response = h.send(req).getBody();
    System.debug('response= '+response);
    Map<String,Object> rmp = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeuntyped(response);
    String apmid = (String)rmp.get('id');
```

Src  : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apextriggermember.htm

---

**UPDATE :** 
To update the trigger, you have to provide the id of the existing trigger in `ContentEntityId`

So your request to create ApexTriggerMember will be :

```
{"MetadataContainerId" : "1dc1l000000BN8IAAW", "FullName" : "MyTrigger" , "Body": "Trigger MyTrigger on Account(after insert,after update){}" , "ContentEntityId": "01q1l000000CnSoAAK"}
```

This gets success respone, and then you can post to `ContainerAsyncRequest` endpoint to update trigger.

Comment: Hey I am able to create trigger using tooling API. I am facing issues updating the trigger using ApexTriggerMember in tooling API.

Below is the response I am getting
 [{"message":"No such column 'ContentEntityId ' on sobject of type ApexTriggerMember","errorCode":"INVALID_FIELD"}]

Comment: @YogeshPatil shown an example to update trigger.